# cancel block request in already deallocated object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

so i'm using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking) for doing asynchronous requests with web-services.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation operationWithRequest:request success:^(id JSON)
    {
        [self doSomeStuff];

    } failure:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        XLog("%@", error);
    }];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
```

now what happens when the "self" object is dealloced before the request finished is, that my application chrashes on `[self doSomeStuff];` of course.

is there a way to cancel this block-request when deallocating my object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some sample code and the result can interest to you.

I created a class that creates a request just like yours:

```
@implementation Aftest
@synthesize name = _name;
- (void) doSomeStuff
{
    NSLog(@"Got here %@", self.name);
}

- (void)startDownload
{   
      self.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name"];
      NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2"];
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
      AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation operationWithRequest:request success:^(id JSON)
      {
           [self doSomeStuff];

      } failure:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
      {
           NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
      }];

      NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
      [queue addOperation:operation];
}
@end
```

And called this with:

```
Aftest *af = [[Aftest alloc] init];
NSLog(@"1 - retain count %d", [af retainCount] );
[af startDownload];
NSLog(@"2 - retain count %d", [af retainCount] );
[af release];
NSLog(@"3 - retain count %d", [af retainCount] );
```

The result that I got was:

```
2011-10-09 09:28:41.415 aftes[6154:f203] 1 - retain count 1
2011-10-09 09:28:41.418 aftes[6154:f203] 2 - retain count 2
2011-10-09 09:28:41.419 aftes[6154:f203] 3 - retain count 1
2011-10-09 09:28:43.361 aftes[6154:f203] Got here name
```

Your object should be retained when passed inside the block. It should be avoiding these crashes.

Either way, as Micheal answered, it should be possible to call `cancel` as long as you have access to the operation object.

Comment: you are right. i used a class in my complete block that i only assigned to my object, where this block lives. retaining this class and releasing it on dealloc works fine now. thank you!

Comment: Note that retainCount can never return 0 and cannot be used to prove that an object remains viable for any given duration.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, you should be able to call `cancel` to stop the operation.